# django AdminDateWidget: Uncaught ReferenceError: quickElement is not defined

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to use AdminDateWidget in my application, I get below javascript error, tried different options available on the internet still couldn't solve. FYI, my admin url is "/newadmin"

I have properly include the form.media, where am I making mistakes?

Console error;

```
DateTimeShortcuts.js:259 Uncaught ReferenceError: quickElement is not defined
    at Object.addCalendar (DateTimeShortcuts.js:259)
    at init (DateTimeShortcuts.js:46)
```

My template looks like;

```
  {% block style %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newadmin/jsi18n/"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="/static/myn/starter.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/myn/starter.js"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
  {% endblock %}
```

Form;

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

#class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
#        from_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'ondate', 'photo', 'desc']
        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'size': 70}),
            'ondate': AdminDateWidget(),

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the Django core.js file.

The docs in calendar.js say this:
depends on core.js for utility functions like removeChildren or quickElementjsi18nurl